# NoMethodError: undefined method `model_name' for Fixnum:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I run an RSpec testcase that fills a form and submits it. I get the following error:

```
1) Sign Up Advertiser after adding valid information should create a user
   Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :user_key)
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `model_name' for Fixnum:Class
   # /mnt/hgfs/Projekte/adserve.example.de/app/controllers/advertisers_controller.rb:31:in `tryToCreateUser'
   # /mnt/hgfs/Projekte/adserve.example.de/app/controllers/advertisers_controller.rb:14:in `create'
   # ./sign_up_advertiser_spec.rb:32:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # ./sign_up_advertiser_spec.rb:32:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is the code for the controller:

```
class AdvertisersController < ApplicationController

 ...

  def home
    @menuindex = 0
  end

  def create
    @user = Advertiser.new (params[:advertiser])
    tryToCreateUser
  end

  def tryToCreateUser
    if @user.save
      @user = Advertiser.retrieve(@user.id)

      redirect_to home, :notice => "You successfully signed up " + @user.full_name
    else
      render :action => "/users/new", :layout => 'application'
    end
  end
end
```

And this is what the routes.rb looks like

```
match "signup_advertiser" => "advertisers#new", :as => "signup_advertiser"
match "signup_publisher" => "publishers#new", :as => "signup_publisher"

get "advertisers_home" => "advertisers#home"

resources :advertisers
```

So I guess the mistake is in the redirect_to part. But I can't figure it out. I fiddled around with rendering a custom action in 'home' and some other stuff. I think it's something pretty basic so help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful with method calls. `new (...)` and `new(...)` can be interpreted as different things. The proper way is to avoid having spaces.

Comment: oops. good spot there. I guess the whole code is just heavily error-ridden...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem is there. You should use home as a symbol on the redirect_to method:

```
def tryToCreateUser
  if @user.save
    @user = Advertiser.retrieve(@user.id)
    redirect_to :home, :notice => "You successfully signed up " + @user.full_name
  else
    render :action => "/users/new", :layout => 'application'
  end
end
```

What you do now is: `redirect_to 0` since you are actually calling the controllers method "home".

Comment: Oh my god. I'm a moron. Thanks a lot good sir. Now I get a new error though: NoMethodError: undefined method `home_url' for #AdvertisersController:0x000000055945c0>' I will mark your answer as correct though.

Comment: Ok, run `rake routes` and see at which path is your home method routed to. You might need `advertisers_home_path` instead of the `:home`

Comment: I've found `redirect_to(home_path(...))` is preferable to `redirect_to(:home, ...)` since it's more clear what you're trying to do. Using `_url` methods instead of `_path` is usually redundant, and can be problematic if you have a site responding to multiple host names.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will keep this answer marked as correct as it corrects the glaring mistake in my code.